# MySQL VIEWS accessing old DB. Cannot edit `information_schema'. Cannot add new rows. Repair advice please

Tags: mysql, database, repair

I am using HeidiSQL. Moved to a new version of my DB. I now seem to have two problems. Any advice on how to repair.

1) I have several views which have greatly simplified queries BUT the now refer to the old DB.

I checked in `information_schema` and sure enough in the `VIEWS` table there, my views are referencing the old DB. But when I try to edit I get: `SQL Error (1044): Access denied for use root@localhost to database information_schema`. (I am logged in as root.)

Not all views are hard coded. Some are `select table1, table2 etc` but others are `select database.table1, database.table2 etc`. When I created this new version (exported old SQL then imported into a new empty DB) I had errors showing when it got to the views. There was something about "algorithm" and then it had a second go and appeared to create them.

2) Normally in HeidiSQL you can just add a blank row to a table and then edit it. I can now edit the name but I cannot specify the`DATATYPE` (EDIT even odder in  `information_schema` (and some of my older DBs) if I try to add a row then the default `DATATYPE` VARCHAR is shown but with my two newer DBs the  `DATATYPE` field is blank and I cannot enter one.)

I have used `Maintenance` in HeidiSQL but it does not seem to fix this problem. I have restarted MySQL (but not the computer yet).

Any thoughts? I only moved to Heidi as phpMyAdmin managed to completely scramble a DB some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code for each view by hand.

I deleted the old views and then created views again with the same names. That worked fine. Took a while to think of the obvious solution.

If you hit the same problem and find this useful please give me an up vote.

I will be uploading the DB to the production server a table at a time and carefully checking the SQL. If you hit this problem suggest vigilance as I suspect problems can easily reappear.

Answer (score 0):

1.my.ini or my.cnf

```
$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

2.sh mysql

```
$mysql -u root mysql
$mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

3.Finally, restart the instance/daemon without the --skip-grant-tables option.

```
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

4.You should be able to connect with your new password.

```
$ mysql -u root -p

Enter password: my_password
```